# Помогите реализовать подобную смену фото в карточке товара без подключения плагина

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

http://xn--80abcmrynbgsbm9gwb.xn--p1ai/plaginy/plitochnaya-galereya/

Я так понимаю, что при наведении на определенную часть блока включается соответствующая картинка, но не совсем понимаю как это реализуется при различном количестве картинок

Answer (score 0):

всем картинкам ставиться

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

и они накладываются друг на друга

потом одной картинки

```
img:nth-child(1) {
    display: block;
}
```

далее

```
$('img').hover( function (e){ 

  e.preventDefault();
  $('img').css({ display: 'none' }) 
  $(e.targget).css({ display: 'block' }) 

} )
```

Comment: Очевидно, что это неполное решение